# I want to change HDD to SSD, but also upgrade to win10

Tags: windows-10, ssd

I have a laptop that came with win8. I did the free upgrade to win10 awhile ago. I recently got a new SSD for the laptop. What things do I need to take into account if I want to install the new SSD? Will I be able to install win10 successfully?

Comment: Of course you will.

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose the right replacement SSD drive

   - some drives, like Samsung EVO or Kingston sets, come with bundled/downloadable cloning software that can save you huge amount of troubles
   - if you plan to install into M.2 slot, make sure that the slot really supports hard disks, not all M.2 slots do, especially in laptops. There are also limitations in BIOS of M.2 slots for some laptops (like only size of 120 GB supported for older HP ProBooks). Also carefully check the physical length of the disk.
2. Check if your original drive is GPT or MBR (using `diskmgmt.msc`)- if it is GPT, you will need newer cloning software, like that bundled with Samsung.
3. Connect your new SSD disk to your PC (either by SATA or USB). You can run Samsung Data Migration software directly from your current Windows 10 and copy your current disk with Win10 to the new disk. It is called [Data Migration Software](http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools.html), or Acronis true image, there are other tools too.
4. Install new disk into a PC and check if everything is running - **no need to reinstall**.
5. Format your old disk and buy [a cheap USB 3.0 HDD enclosure](http://www.ebay.com/sch/2-5-Computer-Drive-Enclosures-and-Docks/158817/bn_746350/i.html) (you can use it in step 3) or install in the box as a secondary disk. If you do not format, you will have to use disk management in Windows to make it visible (because of its ID, which is the same as the new cloned SSD disk).

Comment: I assume that the data migration only works if my SSD is larger or equal storage size to my HDD?

Comment: No, it works from bigger to smaller too.